# How to display trailing whitespace in Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I'm using an Oracle APEX 18.2 interactive report to display some data of type NVARCHAR2 in an APEX column of type "Plain Text." Some data includes trailing spaces. When I view the interactive report, the trailing spaces are not shown. How can I prevent APEX from trimming the whitespace from NVARCHAR2 or VARCHAR2 data?

I've looked for a setting in the column attributes, but could not find anything that would change this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find this supported in the apex attributes natively, but you can control the formatting by using custom css. Tobias Arnold describes a similar problem in this blog: https://www.apex-at-work.com/2018/03/interactive-report-standard-column.html

- Give the column you want to format a static id "description".
- In page properties > CSS > Inline put

```
.a-IRR-table tr td[headers*="description"]
{
    white-space: pre;
}
```